# Invoice Print in vb.net or c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, printing, invoice

I'm making a simple one-form Invoice bill printing, below is the screenshot to illustrate it.

[image]

I want to generate a report from the existing form after entering the data, simply static without database. Only the combo-box values are fetched from the database.

How can I generate that report after clicking the print button. The resultant report should not have combo-box, it should simply have a label instead of it.

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers.  You'll have to be more specific.  Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: specific ? i want to generate a crystel report from this form after entering data , the total , grand total etc. will be calculated automatically. just want to generate a report from this form without database ..

Comment: answer if u can. dont down the question reputation. just new in visual studio not a noob at all .. .

Comment: +1 for asking legitimate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always prefer to generate html files as reports. Its very flexible and printer friendly.
Create a html template with place holders and just replace with your required data.

Comment: how to generate html file from an existing form in vb.net or c# ?

Comment: @Bhavesh look at this link [http://jsfiddle.net/JNJXw/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/JNJXw/1/). In that I have constructed html template somewhat similar to yours. In that template you will find words in CAPITAL letters. These capital letters are place holders. Save this file as a template html file and read it through your program and replace placeholder with required data e.g. MOBILE_NUMBER replace it with whatever mobile number in your case. After doing that save it with some name and timestamp and open through your program. I hope you have understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via html like cloudlight suggest. But I have done it in another way using richtextboxcontrol. This is the link for the class file. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812425

I did receipt printing for POS machine before, I found it very easy to create a rtf file as my template. Then using the richtextboxcontrol, i read in the rtf file content, and replace the segment I want to changes.

For example, if name is a variable, in my rtf file, I would put something like `<NAME>`, after reading, all I need to do is to use string.replace.

Depends on how you customized it, I did it to the extend that I was able to change single variable and multiple lines of item using the same template.